# How do I apply force to an object that must move with the forehead?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

See picture below. So I make a small square object that must be Rigid Body in the BGE physics panel or else I can't apply Servo Motion force via code/Logic Brick. Good so far - the small object falls to platform and I can apply force in x/y/z direction. Now I need the small object to move where the baby's head moves to. These will move face bones. When I give it a Rigid Body Joint, it works, and it has a x/y/z location limit, however the small object falls like 1 inch and stops at its limit and so does the skin because the object has mass, and shouldn't have mass... Help?

I know I can get this to work mechanically or control bones by animation but that's lots of work for either way...ex. I must make all possible animation speeds plus save them as run code!...[image]

Answer (score 2):

I solved it. Found a blend showing what I needed.

http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/phpB...69367c52979f40

If you're up for seeing it yourself in action, all I did was add 3 bricks below there's (of the top cube) that makes it move ex. left when you press A. I used Simple Motion. And was able to record it into Cycles. Looks good. Gravity is natural anyways and won't show up in the face springs.